# How to start and stop a windows service on a schedule?

Tags: c#, windows-services

I have a service that I have written to perform batch duties, but a requirement is to start the processing at 4:00pm and end its processing at 5am. If there is a job still processing, the time would need to be extended until the job is finished.

Would I wrap the onstart call in a timer or what? I really dont know what this would look like as I am used to services starting and running until infinity (or until the box tanks.. or an unhandled exception is met).

I would definitely appreciate some ideas on how to achieve this.

Edit: I do need a service because I am executing an SSIS package through dtexec() and a batch file in C#. Some other things have to happen as well like logging to a dbase and queue management.

Each job has a varying time length, some will complete in a few minutes, others make take 5 hours.

Comment: Why do you want to stop the service rather than just stopping its processing?

Comment: If the second process is dependent on the first then it makes no sense to even attempt to run the second process until the first process has completed.. if the two process are totally independent of one another and do not share the same data i.e Database tables updates, inserts, deletes, etc... then sounds like you would have to run the first process until it's completely finished..

Comment: The is no need for a service. Just schedule a Task. It will run until finished

Comment: @M.Babcock I guess you are right. I miss used my words there. I do want to stop processing but not stop the service.

Comment: @Erno I need a service because I am executing an SSIS package through dtexec & a batch file.

Comment: @fullNelson - If you're in SQL Server already, the SQL Server Agent provides this ability.

Comment: @M.Babcock What ability are you specifically referring to? I know that you can run the files from ssms. To better clarify, I have clients that drop files into ftp, my process picks the files up and enters them into a db. Based on the order they are entered (date time) my process fires off the ssis package on this schedule, but only 1 can run at time. When one finishes the other is released and is operated on by the ssis package.

Comment: @fullNelson - Sounds like you've defined the requirements of a SQL Agent Job. What part doesn't work for you? We do something similar where I work and it *works* (it's not pretty or elegant but it works).

Comment: @M.Babcock Its not that it doesn't work yet, I just don't know my options. This is a project for work and I have a set of requirements I need to see with the skills I have. I only know .NET and SQL syntax to get my work done. But, if you are saying that SQL Agent can do this then Ill go to the DBAs and ask about it. If it works, then yay thats one less thing off my shoulders. I appreciate it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Three options:

1. You could use Windows task scheduler and start the task at the designated time and then keep track within the program how long the task has been running.
2. Have the service constantly "running" but sleeping for a certain amount of time between executions.  This would lead to problems if the program ran longer than anticipated, however.
3. Set the service to run at 15 minutes (or so) intervals and check to see what time it is.  If it is during your starting period, start the program.

The first and 3rd seem like the best options.

Comment: The task scheduler is appealing, but I wonder if you can keep the service running beyond its shutdown time when it has a job it needs to finish. Like I said, its an SSIS package I am firing off through dtexec in C#. The job has to complete, even if the shutoff time goes beyond 5am. I like option 3 the best so far.

Answer (score 4):

This sounds like a task that is better handled by the Windows Task Scheduler.  Unless you're running something like Win2K or XP, it has all the settings necessary to start at a certain time, allow it to run for a limited amount of time, it can start the process under specific credentials (if you need it to run elevated), as well as run when no one is logged on.

And it has a nice handy GUI for managing it all, no coding necessary!

**UPDATE**

OK, based on your comments, what you really need is a workflow.  What I would do, is develop each of the individual tasks in a seperate project (seperate .exe, or .dll depending on your needs).  And then look and [Windows Workflow Foundation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/netframework/aa663328) and develop a workflow "controller" that you can use to run the individual tasks.

Comment: Yeah, I agree with all you said. The only constraint to not using it in my case would be that the service has to finish its processing even if it exceeds the time limit. I am fairly sure this can't be done with TS. Correct me if I am wrong.

Comment: Yes, you are wrong.  I'm not sure what the point in having a "time limit" is if you're not actually going to apply that limit.  But yes, you can kick off the task, and just let it run until it's complete and then it's stops and it's done.  Am I missing something?

Comment: The application is basically a job processing queue. There are mixed jobs with different processing times. Some will stop before 5am and others may take all night, in which case we may run only one job from 4pm to 5am+. If a job finishes at 4:59am processing must stop and let our other services running against that DB continue their work. That's the purpose of the time limit.

Comment: WWF is an an avenue I am planning on focusing on in the coming months to handle these types of "planned" procedures. Given that your suggestion is to use WWF, I will definitely consider it for this project and get started now.

Answer (score 1):

I think that the service should be ran until infinity and check the time to see if it's 4:00pm already and if so, start it's work, and when 5am strikes, just finish up and whait for 4:00 pm again.

Answer (score 1):

what you're looking for is a [scheduled job](http://windows.microsoft.com/en-US/windows7/schedule-a-task)

if you /must/ have a windows service, you use Timers and set the timer to check once every (whenever, I use 30 minutes for this sort of thing) and if the time is between 4am and 5am, do work.

Comment: I do have to use a service because I am handling the execution of a process. Its basically to fire off an SSIS package through dtexec and a batch file. The SSIS package has to complete before the service can terminate.

Answer (score 1):

You could have a look at [quartz.net](http://quartznet.sourceforge.net), it is a good scheduling library that does this sort of thing and can run in process to your service.

Comment: Actually, this is a nice toolset. I spent the time to read what its all about. I dont know if I am going to use it this time, but +1 for the idea.